# Java Wrapper for KotH

Tags: discussion

## Description

This is a Java wrapper class for communicating with submissions written in other languages. If you decide to use this for a challenge, make your life easier and require submissions to post the command that runs it. If they can't run it from the command prompt, then you probably can't either.

**TODO**

There are a few things that I want to add but don't have time to finish right now. I'm also not sure how legal it is to redistribute some of the things that I want to redistribute.

- Bundle a bunch of compilers for popular languages with the wrapper

## Wrapper

```
// Your package line goes here

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Wraps a submission in a Java class.
 * @author Rainbolt
 */
public class Wrapper {

    private final String command;

    /**
     * Create a submission with the specified command.
     * @param command The command associated with the submission
     */
    public Wrapper(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    /**
     * Invokes a submission and returns its response.
     * @param timeout The number of milliseconds allowed for the submission 
     * to respond
     * @return The output of the submission
     */
    public String getResponse(long timeout) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            // Start the process
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            // Attach a reader to the process
            BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            // Allow the process to time out
            proc.waitFor(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (proc.isAlive())
                proc.destroy();

            // Read the output of the process
            while (pin.ready())
                response += pin.readLine() + System.lineSeparator();

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred while attempted to get a response.");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

## Typical Usage

In the example below, the program called SubmissionOne.py is saved to my C: drive. It will receive four arguments (everything after "python"). It has 1000 milliseconds to produce output before being forcibly terminated.

```
long timeout = 1000;
String command = "python C:\\SubmissionOne.py 123 324 345";
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(command);
String response = wrapper.getResponse(timeout);
```

Comment: Oh look, some of this code found its way into my KOTH controller.  How ever did that happen?  (Thanks)